# cassandra write, multi thread

Tags: configuration, cassandra

i have some problem with cassandra 2.1.8
and i'm using the cassandra-driver-core-2.1.6.jar
i'm using 10 of thread doing insert to cassandra about 50000 rows(each thread) at the same time.
but, some thread is very slow. some thread time is very different from the others.( the time, it takes to insert 50000 rows).
i think need to tuning on cassandra.

this is part of my code.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
        bind = statement.bind("KEY" + i + thread + j, param);
        resultSetFuture = session.executeAsync(bind);
        if(i % 1000 == 0) {
            futures.add(resultSetFuture);
            for(ResultSetFuture future : futures) {
                future.getUninterruptibly();
            }
        }
    }
```

can you help me?
please....
Should I need to change any settings?

Answer (score 0):

1) How many cassandra nodes do you have?

2) What are they doing when you run thate code?

3) What's your schema?

4) How many requests per second do you think you should be able to do?

5) What are you basing the answer to #4 on?